# CSS a:Hover is messing up

Tags: html, css, hover, click

I am trying to use separate CSS LINK styles on different classes. The links are messing up when I "HOVER" on the link.  How can I fix this so there is not a different css style showing  when I HOVER OVER the link?

Here is the CSS that is related.

```
.menuButton {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-image: url(../images/menuItems/Rosary-Bead-Icon.png);
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 2.7em;
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
}
.menuButton a:Link ,a:Visited,a:Active, a:Hover{
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Buttons a:Link ,a:Visited,a:Active,a:Hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(../images/menuItems/buttons/largeBlueUp.png);
    height: 57px;
    width: 250px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 55px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The first thing to fix is the 404 error when trying to access http://massmediamail.com/css/HolyRosary-01.css

Comment: There are duplicate `<link href="css/HolyRosary-01.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` and another `<link href="../css/HolyRosary-01.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` in your source.

Comment: I'm not getting any issues.  Everything becomes capitalized when I hover.  When I click it becomes lowercase again, because a new page has loaded.  Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: No I didn't want the Caps on the vertical links. They are taking the "caps" from the top menu, but they should not.

Comment: Jason, even tho there are duplicates that should not matter right? The reason for this is because when I design the pages they are separate from the main css so I need to see what the styles look like as I am designing the page.

Comment: The duplicates are showing twice in the tools I'm using to view things in my browser. Cleaning those up to a single `link` in the `head` would make it easier for others to dive in and solve your scope problem.

Comment: Ah, ok. I will remove it for now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: One of the nice things about presenting a problem using a tool like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is that it lets others play with the code and then present back to you what they found. When I'm looking at code for a website I'm likely to go and [validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmassmediamail.com%2FPrayTheRosary%2F%3Fp%3DHome&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) it at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I got distracted by other issues with the page. The answer is right in the code you shared:

```
.Buttons a:Link ,a:Visited,a:Active,a:Hover
```

and

```
.menuButton a:Link ,a:Visited,a:Active, a:Hover{
```

reads:
 - .Buttons a:Link
 - a:Visited
 - a:Active
 - a:Hover

Change to:

```
.Buttons a:Link, .Buttons a:Visited, .Buttons a:Active, .Buttons a:Hover {
```

and

```
.menuButton a:Link, .menuButton a:Visited, .menuButton a:Active, .menuButton a:Hover {
```

As what you were doing was applying the style to every a on hover.

Comment: That was it! THANK YOU Jason! Thank you so much!